# Is every irreducible representation of $Sp(m)$ a representation of $U(2m)$?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, induced-representations

If $Sp(m)$ is the group of linear automorphisms of $\mathbb{C}^{2m}$ which fix a complex symplectic form $\omega$ and a quaternionic structure $j$ on $\mathbb{C}^{2m}$, then it is clear that $Sp(m)$ is a subgroup of $U(2m)$ (indeed $\omega(j-,-)$ is a hermitian inner product on $\mathbb{C}^{2m}$). If $V$ is a complex irreducible representation of $Sp(m)$, is $V$ also a representation of $U(2m)$, such that when you restrict the action to $Sp(m)$, you recover the original one?

This probably has to do with the concept/construction of an *induced* representation, which I shall read very soon.

Assuming the answer to the previous question was positive, is there a known generalized statement where $Sp(m)$ would get replaced with an arbitrary compact semisimple Lie group, please? (Note: are these questions better suited for Math.SE perhaps?)

Edit: it turns out that, for my own purposes, I do not need the strong statement above to be true, and actually, that statement is false, as one can see from @testaccount's family of counterexamples in the comment section. What I would like to be true, instead, is the statement described in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4781045/are-the-weights-of-an-irreducible-representation-of-a-complex-semisimple-algebra. For my purposes, I am hoping that statement to be true, but I am not sure if it is either.

Comment: You best google the term "Highest Weight Theory". By this, irreducible representations are in bijection with dominant weights. If the groups in question have a common maximal torus, you have a chance. Then the weight groups and the Weyl groups need to coincide.

Comment: This is absolutely not true. You can read a description of the irreducible representations of the symplectic group in Fulton-Harris.

Comment: No, in general if you have groups $H < G$, you would not expect that representations of $H$ can be extended to $G$. Here is a possible example. Let $V = \mathbb{C}^{2m}$. Then $\wedge^2(V)$ is irreducible for $U(2m)$, but has a submodule $W$ of codimension $1$ for $Sp(m)$. This submodule $W$ is not a representation of $U(2m)$

Comment: Thank you Dan Petersen, testaccount and Echo. Yes, my question was a too naive generalization based on 1 example only. The representations described by testaccount are definitely counterexamples for each $m > 1$. For the sake of this post though, can either of you provide a short answer? Or do I just delete the post?

Comment: No reason to delete the post in any case. I checked the details of testaccount's example and it works, although it isn't that short; I can write it up if @testaccount doesn't want to.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer, any idea about my question in the linked post please?

Comment: @DavidESpeyer: I don't have time to write a detailed answer, but probably most of the details are in Fulton-Harris. For example, the irreducibility of $W$ for $Sp(m)$ is a special case of Theorem 17.5, page 260. Also I don't remember if Fulton-Harris talk about unitary groups, but one can use the facts about representations of $GL_{2m}$. (Because algebraic representations of $U(2m)$ extend to $GL_{2m}$.)

Comment: @DavidESpeyer, I guess it is up to you. I get the basic idea behind testaccount's counterexamples. But it may benefit some readers. I personally do enjoy reading your representation theory answers because I do learn from them (I am a differential geometer, by training, and I never took any representation theory class).